# R Cran can't connect to package pages

Tags: r

I'm having a problem accessing R information.  Normally when I google something like:

```
r randomforest
```

I'll get results like these:

```
CRAN - Package randomForest

[PDF] Package 'randomForest'
```

that link to package pages or pdf user manuals.  For the last week or so I get the following error whenever I try to search for package manuals or information and click on the returned links:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
cran.r-project.org
Mon Jan 2 06:44:23 2012
Apache/2.2.21 (Debian)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.  I'm using R 2.14 on a windows 7 machine.  I use firefox but did recently install IE 9 but don't use it.  Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Bad Link example : [CRAN - Package randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html)

Comment: can you give any examples of the returned link? maybe that particular cran server is down.

Comment: how would i switch cran servers?

Comment: Huh, that's odd! Looks like `cran.r-project.org` package mirror is down. You can pick another mirror from here: http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html and go to the `Packages` page (left hand menu) to browse for it. You basically take your link and replace the `http://cran.r-project.org` with (e.g.) `http://cran.stat.sfu.ca` (a mirror in Canada), which looks to be currently working.

Comment: As DWin mentioned, this is a website issue at CRAN that will be resolved eventually I'm sure (keep in mind it's a holiday weekend). You can read more about it [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-December/062922.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what's behind it, but Martin Maechler posted a backup link on r-devel a couple of days ago:

http://cran.CH.r-project.org/web/packages/

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the package pages are available again.  [Brian Ripley recently posted this news](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-January/062927.html).